# Adding a p12 certificate in krakenD gateway

Tags: api-gateway, gateway, krakend, kraken.com

I'm new to krakenD gateway, I want to add p12 certificate in krakenD gateway? Where can add it and how can I use it for particular api?

Answer (score 0):

All certificates in KrakenD use the PEM format, and you have to load them under the TLS section: https://www.krakend.io/docs/service-settings/tls/

If you have non-PEM certificates, you can convert them to PEM using a conversion tool.